# How to lookup a match in two data frames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list, jupyter-notebook

I have two data frame df and df1. I would like to lookup a match (df) in row 0 to 5 in df1 and only return the matching values and range.
For example below

```
import collections
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[2],
                [23],
                [14],
                [33],
                [35],
                [26]], 
                columns = ['Col1'])


df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,4,5,6,8,-19],
                [5,6,20,22,23,34,50],
                [8,12,13,34,45,46,23],
                [9,10,14,29,32,33,-10],
                [1,22,13,23,33,35,2],
                [1,6,7,8,9,10,6],
                [0,2,3,5,6,8,23]], 
                columns = ['Num1','Num2','Num3','Num4','Num5','Num6','Range'])
```

I would like my result like this.

```
result = pd.DataFrame([[2,-19],
                [2,23],
                [23,50],
                [23,2],
                [14,-10],
                [33,-10],
                [33,2],
                [35,2]], 
                columns = ['Match','Range'])
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how exactly are you generating the `result`?

Comment: by finding a match and return the matching values and range

Comment: are you finding a match for `col1` in df and *any* col in df1 and returning the `range` col?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code:

```
df2 = df1.melt(id_vars='Range', value_vars=['Num1', 'Num2', 'Num3', 'Num4', 'Num5', 'Num6']) #reshape for easy filter
result = df2[df2['value'].isin(df['Col1'])] # rows based filter
result = result.rename(columns={'value': 'Match'})
print(result[['Match', 'Range']])
```

Output:

```
    Match  Range
7       2    -19
13      2     23
17     14    -10
25     23      2
29     23     50
32     33      2
38     33    -10
39     35      2
```

Comment: Worked. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas.DataFrame.melt) and [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

```
(df.rename(columns={'Col1': 'Match'})
   .merge(df1.melt('Range', value_name='Match')
             .drop(columns='variable')
         )
)
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you so much.